# execute before open dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following script. When I click on dropdown, it is working well in Chrome and firefox. But on IE, I it needs double click to open dropdown field with data.

```
$("#dp2").focus(function() {
var $secondChoice = $("#dp2");
        $secondChoice.empty();
$secondChoice.append("<option>Select</option>"
+"<option>" + $("#team3").val() + "</option>"
+"<option>" + $("#team4").val() + "</option>");
})
```

What is the perfect way to get data from text field and then dropdown field will open with those entered data?

Comment: populate the list *before* the focus, either on load or on focus / click / change of another element.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited / new update** - checking whether populated first ...

```
 var _populated = false;

$('#dp2').on('focus',function(e) {

    if( !_populated) {
      /* stop the select from opening */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* populate */
      var $secondChoice = $(this); /* can use this */
      $secondChoice.empty();
      $secondChoice.append('<option>Select</option>'
        +'<option>' + $'#team3').val() + '</option>'
        +'<option>' + $('#team4').val() + '</option>');

       _populated = true;
       $secondChoice.focus();
    }
});
```

---

This time round, did create a demo - 
http://jsfiddle.net/HGtJZ/

---

If need to 're populate' can then set `_populated=false` in your other program logic and it will remake.